Static problem regarding the probability that one of the two Blooms is the origin of the specimens.
I have a statistical problem for which I cannot find an approach.
Background I am investigating microorganisms,in each case 47.6% of which originate from one of 2 mass occurrences (1 mass occurrence in January, February and 2. in September, October November. So we do heave a total of 95.2% wich occoure during the mass occurences). The remaining 4.8 per cent of the organisms come from the months between March and August.
Now I have all the microorganisms in a batch and take 10 individuals. How likely is it that in the 10 microorganisms I have 4 individuals from each of the two mass occurrences and 1-2 individuals from the months outside the mass occurrences?

If you're anyhow familiar with multinomial distribution, you'll see how this easily solves your problem. Since you have all the probabilities and the number of occurences of each type, you just plug it into the formula.

Update:
Taking your comment into account, let me lead you through the multinomial distribution in your case.
In general, the MD models the probability of counts $n_k$ for each variable $x_k$ in a series of experiments, usually adding up to $n=\sum_{k=1}^{K}n_{k}$. In your case, there are three outcomes, so $K=3$, the number of trials is $n=10$, and the probabilities of each event $x_k$ are as follows:
$$
\begin{array}{cc|l}
\text{Event} & \text{Probability } p_{i}=\mathbb{P}(x_{i}) & \text{Description of the event:} \\  
x_1 & p_{1}=0.476 & \text{Taking out a specimen from the first occurence} \\ 
x_2 & p_{2}=0.476 & \text{Taking out a specimen from the second occurence} \\
x_3 & p_{3}=0.048 & \text{Taking out a specimen from the rest of occurences} \\
\end{array}
$$
With this in mind, we can use the multinomial probability mass function as follows:
$$
\mathbb{P}(\#x_1=n_1, \#x_2=n_2, \#x_3=n_3)=\frac{n!}{n_1!n_2!n_3!}p_1^{n_1}p_2^{n_2}p_3^{n_3}
$$
In your problem you ask for $n_1=4, n_2=4,$ and $n_3=2$:
$$
\mathbb{P}(\#x_1=4, \#x_2=4, \#x_3=2)=\frac{(4+4+2)!}{4!4!2!}p_1^{4}p_2^{4}p_3^{2}
$$
If you wonder about the probability of getting any number $n_3$ and the number of others as least $4$, i.e. $n_1, n_2 \ge 4$, then you have to sum the probabilities of all the options:
$$
\begin{array}{ccc|c}
n_1 & n_2 & n_3=n-n_1-n_2 & \mathbb{P}(\#x_1=n_1, \#x_2=n_2, \#x_3=n_3)\\  
4 & 5 & 1 & \frac{10!}{4!5!1!}p_1^{4}p_2^{5}p_3^{1} \\ 
4 & 6 & 0 & \frac{10!}{4!6!0!}p_1^{4}p_2^{6}p_3^{0} \\
5 & 4 & 1 & \frac{10!}{5!4!1!}p_1^{5}p_2^{4}p_3^{1} \\
5 & 5 & 0 & \frac{10!}{4!5!1!}p_1^{5}p_2^{5}p_3^{0} \\
6 & 4 & 0 & \frac{10!}{6!4!0!}p_1^{6}p_2^{4}p_3^{0} \\
\end{array}
$$

Thanks for your answer I think I did this back in School 4 or 5 Years ago so Im not so familiar
